# Return only index zero in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

To create a list with the values that I retrieve from a spreadsheet, I do it like this:

```
result = {'range': 'Winning_Margin!G2:O1000', 'majorDimension': 'ROWS', 
          'values': [['10148734', 'CD Olimpia', 'CD Vida', '1', 
                      '71', '85', '14.00', '1.40', '2-0'], 
                     ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], 
                     ['10024627', 'Sporting Kansas City', 'FC Dallas', 
                      '2', '35', '1', '-34.00', '2.88']]}

for a in result["values"]:
    a.extend([''] * (max(map(len, result["values"])) - len(a)))

spreadsheets_match_id = [item for sublist in result["values"] for item in (sublist or ['']) if sublist[-1] != '']
```

This way returns the entire index:

```
['10148734', 'CD Olimpia', 'CD Vida', '1', '71', '85', '14.00', '1.40', '2-0']
```

But my need is just the first index of each list of list, in this case the result is:

```
['10148734']
```

Tried to make each item become `item[0]` but when trying to do that, it either says that `item` doesn't exist or returns the first letter of each of the list's indexes within the list like `['1', 'C', 'C', '1', '7', '8', '1', '1', '2']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
You can check if the last element of the sublist is `''` or not and keep the first elements of the ones that aren't:

```py
out = [sublist[0] for sublist in result["values"] if sublist[-1] !='']
```

**Old answer:**

IIUC, you want to get the first element of a sublist that is not `''`, right? Then you can create a single element list in a list comprehension and iterate over it in a nested loop to check if it is `''` or not:

```py
out = [item for sublist in result["values"] for item in [sublist[0]] if item !='']
```

Output:

```py
['10148734', '10024627']
```

Comment: Hi @enke, thanks a lot for support, I understood the idea perfectly, just to be more exact with the question, could you please add the detail of the last index (```[-1]```) not equal to ```''``` too? Just to be clear with the question. Thank you very much again!

Comment: The expected result is only ```['10148734']``` because the last list of list the last value is ```''```

Comment: Now it is correct @enke , it is because the expected result is if the list is not empty and also the last value is not empty. The last value after I pass it to equalize all amounts of index looks like this: ```['10024627', 'Sporting Kansas City', 'FC Dallas', '2', '35', '1', '-34.00', '2.88', '']```

Comment: Here it makes all lists within the lists the same size: ```a.extend([''] * (max(map(len, result["values"])) - len(a)))```